# Python kivy game: how can I make a rectangle/ellipse collide with a quad

Tags: python, kivy, game-physics, game-development

I am creating a game but I can't make rectangle collide with the quad shape. It collides when the rectangle is at the middle of the quad and at the right side of the quad but if I move the rectangle to the left side of the quad it does not collide any more. It just the edge of the rectangle goes out or even reaches the left of the quad it will stop colliding.

```
rect = None
rect_coordinates = [(0, 0), (0, 0)]
nb_b = 100
brick = []
brick_coordinates = []

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.init_vertical_line()
    self.init_horizontal_line()
    self.init_brick()
    self.init_ship()
    self.init_rect()
    self.generate_brick_coordinates()
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)

def init_rect(self):
    with self.canvas:
        Color(0, 1, 0)
        self.rect = Rectangle()

def update_rect(self):
    pos_x = self.movement
    pos_y = self.height/1.923
    size_x = self.width/15
    size_y = self.height/25
    self.rect_coordinates[0] = (pos_x, pos_y)
    self.rect_coordinates[1] = (size_x, size_y)
    self.rect.pos = (self.rect_coordinates[0])
    self.rect.size = (self.rect_coordinates[1])

def collided(self):
    for i in range(0, len(self.brick_coordinates)):
        bi_x, bi_y = self.brick_coordinates[i]
        if bi_y < self.current_y_loop:
            return False
        if self.ball_collide_brick(bi_x, bi_y):
            return True
    return False

def ball_collide_brick(self, bi_x, bi_y):
    x_min, y_min = self.get_brick_coordinate(bi_x, bi_y)
    x_max, y_max = self.get_brick_coordinate(bi_x+1, bi_y+1)
    for i in range(0, 1):
        px, py = self.rect_coordinates[i]
        if x_min <= px <= x_max and y_min <= py <= y_max:
            return True
    return False

def init_brick(self):
    with self.canvas:
        Color(1, 1, 1)
        for i in range(0, self.nb_b):
            self.brick.append(Quad())

def get_line_x_from_index(self, index):
    central_x = self.width / 2
    spacing = self.v_line_space * self.width
    offset = index - 0.5
    line_x = central_x + offset * spacing
    return line_x

def get_line_y_from_index(self, index):
    spacing_y = self.h_line_space * self.height
    line_y = index * spacing_y - self.current_y_offset
    return line_y

def get_brick_coordinate(self, bi_x, bi_y):
    bi_y = bi_y - self.current_y_loop
    x = self.get_line_x_from_index(bi_x)
    y = self.get_line_y_from_index(bi_y)
    return x, y

def update_brick(self):
    for i in range(0, self.nb_b):
        bricks = self.brick[i]
        brick_c = self.brick_coordinates[i]
        x_min, y_min = self.get_brick_coordinate(brick_c[0], brick_c[1])
        x_max, y_max = self.get_brick_coordinate(brick_c[0] + 1, brick_c[1] + 1)
        x1, y1 = self.transform(x_min, y_min)
        x2, y2 = self.transform(x_min, y_max)
        x3, y3 = self.transform(x_max, y_max)
        x4, y4 = self.transform(x_max, y_min)
        bricks.points = [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4]
```

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducable example.  What you have provided appears to be the contents of a single class, but missing the class declaration, doesn't include the imports or main loop, etc.  Its not clear what shape is the "quad", and what shape is "the rectangle"

Answer (score -1):

I started programming with python/kivy but with time I saw it wasn't the best option. It's why I recommend you c# (or c++ but it's way harder) with [unity](https://unity.com/en) especially for physics game development (simple to learn, with a lot of tutorial and a bigger community than kivy).
It's only going to take you some hour to understand it and remake what you have here.

PS:I know that I shouldn't "Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience." but I think this is the best solution since you don't have any answer yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).